# How to get EditText references in the onCreate() method?

Tags: android, android-edittext, adapter

Hi I have 49 edittexts in my app for which I used gridview. So, I created an activity whose onCreate() method contains the adapter object. In the custom adapter class I gave count=49. So, 49 edittexts are arranged in the gridview.

But my problem is I want to set some values in the edittexts by default as soon as my activity is visible.(hint attribute doesn't not work in my app, as my default values in the edittexts are generated randomly ). So, after a lot of thinking I retrieved the edittexts' objects by using the following code snippet in my activity class and kept this code in one method.

```
 int k=0;
    for(int i=0;i<editText.length;i++)
      {
        for(int j=0;j<editText.length;j++)
           {
               editText[i][j]=(EditText)gridView.getChildAt(k);
               k++;

            }
      }
```

But this method should be called before the activity is visible.  At the very first time I kept this snippet in the onCreate() method after the statement `gridView.setAdapter(new TextAdapter(this));`   . But no use, the application is showing force close. Later I kept this in onStart(), but no use again, the edittext objects are still unavailable and showing force close. So, to test this, I kept in one method which gets executed when the button is clicked in the activity, then the edittexts objects are available. So, I don't want to set the values after the manual operation(here button click). I want the values to be set automatically before the activity becomes visible. Still any call back methods which solve my problem? I have been searching many sources for this problem and kinda exhausted. Please suggest. Code snippet would be appreciated.

Comment: that part `for(int j=0;j<editText.length;j++)` doesn't do what you want, for one

Comment: (also, if you look at the logcat, you'll find tremendous informations about what your problem is)

Comment: Logcat output would help here.

Comment: your this loop code is not execute before onCreate(). Instead you can make a static method and keep that method there.

Comment: @njzk2 If that loop doesn't work, then how come the same loop is working in onClick() method. I know my problem that edittexts' objects are unavailable in the onCreate() as it can't get the objects until it is drawn. Anyways, thanks for your time.

Comment: @iccthedral Nope. I always use logcat. I explained the problem already. Logcat gives null pointer exception obviously as it is unable to find edittexts objects. Please reply me if you can give the solution.

Comment: you are looping twice on editText.length. unless it is a square matrix, you'll have bounds issues at some point. for the j loop, the length should be editText[i].length

Comment: @nick Thanks for your time. Even if I make that method static, it obviously still can't find the objects. As the edittext objects are created dynamically using adapter class in onCreate(), how can it find the objects in the static method(which gets executed prior to any other method including onCreate()). pls read the entire question.

Comment: @njzk2 it is a two dimensional which is EditText[][] editText=new EditText[7][7]; That's why it works in the other method.

Comment: yes, but the principle is that you iterate on the size of another element that *happens* to have the same size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But my problem is I want to set some values in the edittexts by default as soon as my activity is visible.

No, you don't. You want to set some values in the `EditText` widgets by default before the `EditText` widgets are visible.

> But this method should be called before the activity is visible.

It should never have been written, let alone be called.

> But no use, the application is showing force close.

Of course. At this point, you have precisely zero `EditText` widgets.

> Still any call back methods which solve my problem?

Populate your `EditText` widgets when they are created by your `TextAdapter`, in `getView()` (or `newView()`, if this is a `CursorAdapter`). By definition, you cannot do it before this point, because the `EditText` widgets do not exist.

Comment: Glad you replied to my question. I am using TextAdapter that extends BaseAdapter. But how can I populate EditText widgets in getView and make it available and set values in the onCreate() method or so. Sad, if I follow another approach for which I have to start from the beginning  , my entire work for this app till now goes vain. Can you please suggest alternative?

Comment: @Appu: "But how can I populate EditText widgets in getView and make it available and set values in the onCreate() method." -- that is not possible.

Comment: Yes, of Course I understand your answer. Is there any alternative?

Comment: @Appu: By definition, no. The `EditText` widgets simply *do not exist* at `onCreate()` time.

Comment: Okay. To avoid this I just started the alert dialog in the onCreate() which asks the user whether to start the game. So, when the user gives positive response, then I am setting the intial values in the edittexts in the onCreateDialog(). So, it's working. But when the orientation is changed, I am unable to set the previous values in the edittexts using savedInstanceState() method. As the editText objects are again unavailable due to current activity destruction. If I show again some alertdialog to manipulate this when changed orientation, it is terrible to think even.

Comment: have you tried using the Post event handler for each edit text in oncreate? That should only fore after the view is rendered. editView1.Post(() => {
                editView1.Text = presetValue;
            });